# How to differentiate between the private instance variable and a parameter having same name in java

Tags: java, class, oop, object, access-specifier

There is a keyword `this` in java to access the instant variables which are public. But is there such way to access the private ones

```
class Foo {

    private int a = 2;
    public int b = 3;

    public void test(int a, int b) {
        this.b = b;
        //but how to access a;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Foo x = new Foo();
        x.test(1, 2);
    }
}
```

Above is the code example I have....

Comment: You can free access your class property inside that class.

Comment: `this` access all properties from him, even private.

Comment: Exactly same way as `b` - there is no difference inside class, `private` keyword only hides the field from outside.

Comment: Have you *tried* accessing `a` with `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the same class, both private and public variables can be accessed in the same way:

```
class Foo {

    private int a = 2;
    public int b = 3;

    public void test(int a,int b){
        this.b = b;
        this.a = a; // accessing private field a
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Foo x = new Foo();
        x.test(1,2);
    }
}
```

Comment: can I do x.a inside main

Comment: @gopinadh5g7 No you cannot. That is the difference between public and private access modifiers. Private variables are only accessible within the class itself. Please refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Comment: this is equal to object then how is it possible

Comment: @gopinadh5g7, yes you are right.You can do x.a. I didn't realize main method was  in Foo class itself.

Comment: Sorry I got it this is a keyword and can acess any attribute in the class and never minds what access specifier it is

Answer (score 1):

All class methods have access to their own private members. Hence, `this.a = a` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Follow Java tutorial on [this keword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) it can access private members:

> ```
> private int x, y;
> public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
>    this.x = x;
> ```

Comment: If this can access it then inside main i can use object to do it

Answer (score 0):

A class object can access it's private members, otherwise nothing could access them and they'd be quite pointless. So `this` with private members works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

`Class method` have an access to `private data member` so you can use

```
this.a=a
```